# Expected value for people which doesn't have neighbors on a bar branch

Tags: probability

> 3 people get into a bar and sit randomly on a bench with n-sits. Find the
>
> a.Variance of people which don't have neighbors where $n=5$
>
> b. Expected value for people who don't have neighbors for general n.

First I defined X to be the number of people who don't have neighbors on the bench. About a, I got $P(X=0)=\frac {3\cdot 3!}{\binom{5}{3}}=\frac {3}{10},P(X=2)=0,P(X=3)=\frac {3!}{60}=0.1$ and subtracting these of 1 $P(X=1)=0.6=\frac {36}{60}$ and calculating the variance is trivial.

About B: I can't find even $P(X=1)$. If $n=3, P(X=0)=1,P(X>0)=0$ and otherwise $P(X=0)=\frac {(n-2)\cdot 3!}{\binom n 3}$. For $P(X=1)$ suppose we isolate every time one person, we need to choose him in $\binom 3 1$ ways and we duplicate by 2 for the symmetric ordering and again by 2 for the inner order of the pair. In conclusion we need to find how many different orders (up to reflection) exist. I failed in this mission. for $P(X=3)$ we choose place for first person in $\binom{n}{1}$ ways and then for the second we choose in $\binom{n-3}{1}$ ways (that's why $P(X=2)=\frac{\binom{n}{1}\cdot\binom{n-3}{1}}{\binom {n}{3}}$) but for the last one there can be intersection between the empty places of first man and second one, so I wonder how can I formulate it (of course we duplicate ordering coefficients and divide by $\binom{n}{3}$).

How can I find the ordering in cases of $P(X=1)$ and $P(X=3)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probabilities in (a) look right. There is a typo in the calculation of $\Pr(X=1)$. With the numerator as it is, the denominator should be $(6)(5)(4)$. But you knew that, and got the right answer of $\frac{3}{10}$.

For probability calculations, I would concentrate on the *choices* of seats, and not who sits where.

For (b), the following trick is very useful, particularly if we have quite a lot of people instead of $3$.  Call the people $1,2,3$. Define random variable $X_i$ by $X_i=1$ if person $i$ has no neighbours, and $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then $X=X_1+X_2+X_3$. By the linearity of expectation, we have
$$E(X)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+E(X_3).$$
The expectations of the $X_i$ are all the same, so we find $E(X_1)$.

To find $E(X_1)$, we do it a crude way, by breaking into cases. 
It can be done more simply, by using ideas of the kind discussed in the Remark below.

Maybe $1$ sits at one of the two ends (probability $\frac{2}{n}$).  Given that $1$ is at an end, the probability the seat next to her is unoccupied is $\frac{\binom{n-2}{2}}{\binom{n-1}{2}}=\frac{n-3}{n-1}$.  From this we get a contribution of $\frac{2}{n}\cdot \frac{n-3}{n-1}$.

Maybe $1$ sits not at an end (probability $\frac{n-2}{n}$). In that case the probability both neighbouring seats are unoccupied is $\frac{\binom{n-3}{2}}{\binom{n-1}{2}}=\frac{(n-3)(n-4)}{(n-1)(n-2)}$. Multiply by $\frac{n-2}{n}$.

Add. Things simplify, and we get $\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{n(n-1)}$.

Multiply by $3$ for $E(X)$.

**Remark:** For $3$ people we can use explicit counting. You asked about that.

The easiest is $\Pr(X=2)$, exactly $2$ lonely people. That is impossible. So the probability is $0$.

Next easiest is $\Pr(X=0)$. We can choose $3$ seats in $\binom{n}{3}$ equally likely ways. To make a block of $3$ consecutive, choose the leftmost seat in the block. This can be done in $n-2$ ways. That leaves $1$ lonely and $3$ lonely. 
Counting $3$ lonely feels easier to me.

Write down $n-3$ $X$'s, kind of like this, with space between them.  The $X$'s represent bar stools that will ultimately be empty. 
$$X\qquad X\qquad X\qquad X\qquad X\qquad X\qquad X\qquad X\qquad X\qquad $$
People $1,2,3$ each have their own folding barstools. They will **choose** $3$ "gaps" from the $n-2$ gaps available. It is $n-2$ because the gaps available are the $n-4$ between $X$'s, and the $2$ ends.

The number of choices is $\binom{n-2}{3}$. Now we can compute $\Pr(X=3)$.

We can now compute $\Pr(X=1)$ by subtraction. Or else we can choose a gap for the group  of $2$ ($n-2$ ways). Then there are $n-3$ gaps left, so the number of choices that give $X=1$ is $(n-2)(n-3)$.

Comment: I read your answer again and there are some unclear points for me: Why in the first case (one sits in one of the ends ) you multiply by $\frac{n-4}{n-1}$ and then immediately by $\frac {n-2}{n}$? and where $n-4$ disappeared from the final answer?

Comment: There are issues! The multiply by $\frac{n-2}{n}$ is the result of editing. It is supposed to be **after** the next line, not before. I will go carefully through everything, changing anything that needs to be changed. About $10$ minutes!

Comment: Corrected. The expressions for the end-cases and not end-cases got interchanged during editing.  However, the final result is unchanged. Thanks for spotting the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to part b; instead of looking at the people, look at the seats.  A person has no neighbors if and only if the seat he is sitting in is occupied and has no occupied neighbors.  So let
$$X_i = \begin{cases}
1    &\text{if seat i is occupied and has no occupied neighbors}\\
0    &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
If $i = 1$ or $i=n$,
$$P(X_i = 1) = \frac{\binom{n-2}{2}}{\binom{n}{3}} = \frac{3(n-3)}{n(n-1)}$$
If $1 < i < n$,
$$P(X_i = 1) = \frac{\binom{n-3}{2}}{\binom{n}{3}} = \frac{3(n-4)(n-3)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}$$
So
$$E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i) = 2\cdot \frac{3(n-3)}{n(n-1)} + (n-2) \cdot \frac{3(n-4)(n-3)}{n(n-1)(n-2)} = \frac{3(n-2)(n-3)}{n(n-1)}$$